# Disinstall Vagrant Mac

Tags: permissions, vagrant

I want to disinstall Vagrant and I'm following the documentation:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html

first command to run is :

```
rm -rf /opt/vagrant
```

but here comes the issue. I get the following:

```
...................................
rm: /opt/vagrant/embedded/share/readline/rlcat.c: Permission denied
rm: /opt/vagrant/embedded/share/readline/histexamp.c: Permission denied
rm: /opt/vagrant/embedded/share/readline: Permission denied
rm: /opt/vagrant/embedded/share: Permission denied
rm: /opt/vagrant/embedded: Permission denied
rm: /opt/vagrant: Permission denied
```

I get this message for all files in /opt/vagrant. I tried to use chmod to give me the right to write it but it doesn't work out.

How am I supposed to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant` ?

Comment: yeah, it worked. Thanks @Kevin